# Why there are no tutorials on calculating Gini impurity in a three-valued categorical feature variables?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

Trying to learn here so please go easy on me if I asked dumb questions.

As the title says, I was searching for a tutorial that calculates the Gini in a CART algorithm for a three-valued feature variable. (i.e., assuming we have a feature variable named, "Blood pressure" and it has three levels (low, medium, and High)). However, I didn't find one. A perfect example of that is the Play Tennis problem, we can have a solution using the entropy method, but not with the Gini method.

Comment: CART only ever makes binary splits, is that the underlying misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

There are no categories, you encode these columns as integer ones and proceede as usual.
Gini is there just to help you make decision on how and where you split. Gini,Entropy,variance are all replaceable components.

Comment: hello @Noah-Weber , I can see the result in python (I think you helped me yesterday), but the calculation is not clear, each leaf got split into two leaf nodes (although there are three categories, so this means there is a grouping mechanism,) is this what is going on? if yes, then how come I can't find a tutorial doing that?

Comment: No there is not in certain sence. If your tree finds that 1 2 AND 3 should be all disciminated than in the SECOND split (after the root node) you will split the group that was grouped in the root node. But they are grouped because they are not giving enough information in order to split them explicitly.